# Append jquery, добавление дочерних элементов div-контейнеру

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Столкнулся с проблемой следующего характера: Написал функцию-обработчик события по клику, которая разворачивает див контейнер на весь экран, при этом в нём появляются дочерние элементы (callback-форма, галерея-каруселька итд). Дочерние элементы прописываю следующим способом:

```
var newElems = $("<div class="parent">\
                        <div class="container">\
                            <div class="col-md-12 ">\
                                <div class="raw">\
                                    <div class="ValidationBackground">\
                                        <div class="col-md-12 ">\
                                            <h3>Validation form</h3>\
                                                <form id="myForm"  action="" class="main_form" method="get" novalidate >\
                                                    <div class="form-group has-feedback nameBlock">\
                                                        <label class="control-label" for="fio"> \
                                                            <input id="fio" type="text" name="fio" placeholder="ФИО" class="form-control" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status"/>\
                                                        </label>\
                                                    </div>\
                                                    <div class="form-group has-feedback emailBlock">\
                                                        <label class="control-label" for="email">\
                                                            <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" class="form-control" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status"/>\
                                                        </label>\
                                                    </div>\
                                                    <div class="form-group has-feedback phoneBlock">\
                                                        <label class="control-label" for="phone">   \                   
                                                            <input id="phone" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Телефон +7(999)999-99-99" class="form-control" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status"/>\
                                                        </label>\
                                                    </div>\
                                                    <button id="submitButton" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" name="submit" type="submit" disabled>Отправить</button>\
                                                    <div id="resultContainer" class="result" >\
                                                        <h1>Result</h1>\
                                                    </div>\
                                                </form>\
                                        </div>\
                                    </div>\
                                </div>\
                            </div>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>");
```

а прикрепляю к родителю при помощи append:

```
 $('.container').append(newElems);
```

Когда переменная newElems содержит небольшой кусок html кода - всё работает отлично, но здесь начинаются проблемы (эта запись вообще отзывается работать, ссылаясь на ошибку "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"). Вопрос: Есть ли способ не вставлять огромные html куски в js файл, а например ссылаться на отдельно лежащие html файлы, или, возможно имеется иной, более "правильный" способ реализовать задуманное. Спасибо

Comment: сконкатенируйте это все с помощью самого обычного `+` и будет работать

Comment: Спасибо, но всё же это больше похоже на костыли,. Интересно как это сделать "по науке", ведь js файл не должен содержать в себе огромный html-скелет

Comment: Конкретно тут ошибка в том, что вы везде двойные кавычки поставили. По уму конечно не должно быть разметки в js, но как правило такой подход для jquery нормален (можно аяксом шаблоны подтягивать, но тут и задержки и возможные баги от еще больших костылей). И ещё - я вижу как минимум 4 ненужных обертки, тут достаточно '<div class="container ValidationBackground"' и пошла форма.

Comment: Погуглите "jquery шаблонизатор"

Comment: Благодарю. Да, касательно кучи вложений, в этой форме используется Bootstrap grid, отсюда и необходимость.